# How to concatenate a string in python?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I try to read in a file and output in a single line.

File:

```
how
are
you
```

code:

```
infile = open('input', 'r')
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    print (line)
```

rstrip already strip off `'\n'`,
however the output still spread into 3 lines.

```
how
are
you
```

How to make the print out into single line?

Comment: `print (line, end = "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass empty string to end parameter in `print` function after strippping off the newline character.

```
print (line, end = "")
```

`print` by default print the content in a new line for each iteration  but by passing empty string to the `end` parameter, this default behaviour won't work. If you failed to remove the newline character, it would print the content along with the newline character.

Comment: This will work only with Python 3.x and not Python 2.x

Comment: ya, op used `print (`, so there is a max chance of python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `print()` function is being called independently each time the loop runs. And every time the print runs, the output is started to be printed on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

The title asks for concatenation but the details just ask for output. The `print` answers deals with the latter but if you want to concatenate, then you would use `join` or `+`

```
>>> with open('input', 'r') as infile:
...     output = ""
...     for line in infile:
...         output += line.rstrip('\n')
...     print(output)
howareyou
```

However, given you likely want a space between the strings then I would suggest you look into `join`, which can simply be used in conjunction with a comprehension:

```
>>> with open('input', 'r') as infile:
...     print(" ".join(line.rstrip(`\n`) for line in infile))
how are you
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use python 2.7, the following syntax should work:

```
print line,
```

Answer (score 0):

to make 2&3 compatible, you can:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('hello, world', end='')
```

so your code could be:

```
from __future__ import print_function
infile = open('input', 'r')
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    print(line, end='')
```

or this one:

```
with open('input') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
print(' '.join(lines))
```